# Extract list file from array in nodejs but step one by one nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to extract a list of about 100 files from the array list, but I'm going to extract one by one.

```
 fs.readdir(config.tmp_directory, function(error, files){
    if (error) {
      return callback(error)
    }
    count_file = files.length
    files.map(function(file){
      targz.decompress({
        src:  config.tmp_directory + "/" + file,
        dest: config.extract_directory + "/"
        }, function(err){
            if(err) {
                log_erreur.push(file)
                return count_err =  count_err + 1;
            }
            console.log("file : " + config.extract_directory + "/" + file + " Done!");
            count_succes = count_succes + 1;
            if (count_succes + count_err == count_file) {
              process.stdout.write("\n")
              process.stdout.cursorTo(0);
              process.stdout.write("Extract Sequency Finished...");
              process.stdout.write("\n")
              return callback(null,"next", log_erreur)
            }
        });
    })
  });
};
```

but this code starts all extract file in parallel.

How can I extract one at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) npm module
>   here.

```
fs.readdir(config.tmp_directory, function(item, files){
    if (error) {
        return callback(error)
    }
    count_file = files.length
    async.eachSeries(files,function(item, innercb){
        // do here with item 
        console.log(item)
        innercb()
    }), function(err, result){
        // after finish all files you can call here final callback
        // main callback
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks you, Work fine but this it :

```
fs.readdir(config.tmp_directory, function(item, files){
if (error) {
  return callback(error)
}
count_file = files.length
async.eachSeries(files,function(item, innercb){
// do here with item 
  console.log(item)
 innercb()
}, function(err, result){
   // after finish all files you can call here final callback
   // main callback
   });
});
```

remove ')' in eachSeries and put in  "function(err, result)"

Comment: It looks like you just copy / pasted the code from Manjeet's answer